# How can I use a custom layout and still have the console application work?

Tags: yii, console

I am using a custom layout in Yii. Everything works great in the web part of the app. Then I tried to run the console part of the app to run a job and it says:

exception 'CException' with message 'Property "CConsoleApplication.layout" is not defined.' in /pathToFramework/base/CComponent.php:173

If I revert to the default layout in config/main.php it works again. I can't find any documentation on how to specify the layout only for the console application. I know I can fix it but don't want to get hacky. Does anyone have a clue about the correct wat to go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't need to specify a layout in your config, but rather do that within your controllers if you're overriding things.  That's probably why your `CWebApplication` can handle things (you're giving it a `layout` property in your config), but your `CConsoleApplication` doesn't allow for that property to be set.

Seems like your options are:

1. Specify your layout property in each controller (any reason you couldn't just use the default views/layouts/main.php?)
2. Specify your `layout` property in a config file that is only used for your `CWebApplication` system instead of your `CConsoleApplication`
3. Override your `layout` property in a config file specific to your `CConsoleApplication`

Any of the above should work.